# No response called. Nor succes nor failed in loopj

Tags: android, loopj

In loopj when i hit a URL nor **onSuccess** nor **onFailure** calling that's why my **progressDiaog** keep on running for infinite time.

Comment: just go through this http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: i did not find anything in this doc because in the doc they are explaining only the roles of all methods in the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are implementing the right methods (different onSuccess/onFailure methods have different inputs).
If you are implementing onSuccess with input JSONObject but your WebService is returning a JSONArray, it will not enter there.

Comment: i know what you talking about but it's not happening every time many times its working perfect but few times this situation occur even i do not change anything in the code.

Comment: Put some logs in the "onFinish" method, see if it enters there, and how long it takes.
If it just fails sometimes maybe is your server the one with the issue, so you should check the logs on your backend, see if it fails to deliver the response.

Comment: server don't have any issue because i have implemented same api with retrofit and now it's working fine